# How to retrieve error from function?

Tags: c++, function

Suppose I need to get value from config.

What function is more correctly?

```
int ret;
string value = config.getStringValue(string name, &ret);
```

or

```
string value;
int ret = config.getValue(string name, &value);
```

or maybe

```
string value = config.getStringValue(string name);
int ret = config.getResultCode();
```

And what var name for result code is more correctly: ret, error, etc?

**Update:**
Additional to @computerfreaker's comment: there is no exceptions in same platforms like [bada](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppappprogramming.help/html/basics_bada_programming/exception_handling.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Neither solutions you proposed are the correct C++ way. What you provided is just C. In C++, use exceptions

Comment: Aren't exceptions incur some overhead?

Comment: @arrowdodger execpt if you are working in a very very very very constrained embedded system, the performance hit due to the stack unwinding is perfectly negeible.

Comment: @Manu343726: The real problem with exceptions are the semantics. You should not use them for ordinary behaviour. Wrong user input is not an **exceptional** case, so using exceptions is questionable here.

Comment: [You don't want to use exceptions if you're writing a C++ DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107948/throwing-c-exceptions-across-dll-boundaries), in which case op's question is perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

The way you think is: *"I have to send some status code to the caller"*... this is the way you usually handle errors in C, but since there are exceptions in C++, it's much cleaner and wiser to do:

```
#include <exception>
std::string getValue() {
    if (...)
        throw std::exception("Unable to retrieve value.");
}
```

and caller would do:

```
try {
    std::string val = getValue();
} catch (std::exception& e) { ... }
```

Just remember the rule: ***Throw by value, catch by reference.***

---

Regarding *"exceptions are meant for handling **exceptional states**"*  - it's true. Exceptions should be used in situations when something unexpected / exceptional happens. If function `getValue` relies on the fact that the value exists and it can be retrieved, then the situation when your code for some reason fails to retrieve this value is exceptional and thus suitable for handling it using exceptions.

Comment: Could you comment @ChristianHackl opinion about exeptions and ordinary behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

C++ offers several ways of reporting errors from functions which return a value:

1. Throw an **exception**. This should be done when the cause of the error is with some external resource and does not normally happen. Perfect example: out of memory.
2. Return a **special value** to indicate failure, and follow this convention at the call site. For example, return `""` for errors and have callers check for `""`.
3. Use `std::optional` or a similar technique. That's an advanced version of your first example. The basic idea is to return a **special object which contains the original object** *and* a boolean flag indicating success. The special object is used with the rule that the original object may only be accessed if the boolean flag indicates success. Other names of this idiom which I've heard are "Fallible" and "Box". This solution and the previous one are good candidates when error cases are expected and frequent -- usually a perfect match for user input.
4. **Abort** the program with `assert`. This is a good solution if an error indicates that your own code is wrong. In this case, the best thing to do is usually terminating the program as quickly as possible before it can do any harm.
5. Use **global error state** and have callers check it. That's your third example. C code fancies doing that a lot with `errno`. In C++, however, this is typically not considered a good solution. It's bad for the same reasons that any kind of global variable is typically bad.
6. Do not return the value itself but make it an **out parameter** with a reference. Return an error flag instead. That's your second example. It is better than the previous approach but still very C-like. I would not recommend doing it because it will force callers to name every received value.

Comment: You should separate the C ways from the C++ ways I think.

Comment: Also assert is good for debugging only, don't make your working code depend on assert conditions.

Comment: @Manu343726: This is your opinion, but it is not universally shared by experienced programmers.